# Navigating through records on UserForm Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a userform in Excel VBA, which I will use to view and update certain records from the sheet I have:

[UserForm1 http://im35.gulfup.com/Ay43Z.png](http://im35.gulfup.com/Ay43Z.png)

What I can't seem to figure out is how to make it Navigate between the records in the Sheet which have "Y" in the Status column.

[Sheet1 http://im36.gulfup.com/cq6CN.png](http://im36.gulfup.com/cq6CN.png)

I need the user to be able to edit the Comments column through the UserForm for the records he is viewing so that the changes are saved in the Sheet. The rest of the textboxes on the Userform are set to Locked so that they can only display data.

The problem I'm facing now is that I can only seem to be able to loop between all the records. What I need is to navigate between the ones having "Y" as their "Status". Also, I can't seem to figure out how have the changes made in the Comments box on the form to be saved on the sheet.

Any help would be really appreciated!

**EDIT:**

The below is the code I have for the Previous Button:

```
If CurRecord = 0 Then CurRecord = 1

    With ws
        For i = 1 To (CurRecord - 1)
            If Not .Range("G" & i).Value = "X" Then
                TextBox1.Text = .Range("A" & i).Value
                TextBox2.Text = .Range("B" & i).Value
                '
                '~~> And So on load the rest
                '

                CurRecord = i
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next i

        If (i - 1) = lRow Then
            MsgBox "End of record reached"
        End If
    End With
```

When I use this it keeps jumping to the first record.

I also tried:

`For i = 1 To (CurRecord - 1)`

But this gives me an "Out of Range" error when it reaches the first record.

Wonder where I am going wrong?

Comment: I can help you with it if you upload a sample file in www.wikisend.com and share the link here. I am feeling very lazy to create a sample on my own :p

Comment: @SiddharthRout Sorry for the late response, I was actually out of town for the holidays! Anyway, I uploaded the file as requested: http://wikisend.com/download/461380/Book1.xlsm

Comment: @SiddharthRout I would really appreciate if you could at least drop me some hints. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry was out of town. So where are we stuck now?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thank for the reply. I'm stuck with figuring on how to navigate between records with "Y" in the status. I not sure on how to proceed with the code to be able to go previous and next. I have uploaded the Sheet as requested: https://db.tt/aM7PZIDs  ... PS I modified the comment and re-uploaded the excel file. It seems that the wikisend link was not working correctly.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Link updated in the modified comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very basic example of the `Next` button. Now I am sure you will be able to code the `Previous` Button similarly :)

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim CurRecord As Long

'~~> Load the first record
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lRow
            If .Range("G" & i).Value = "Y" Then
                TextBox1.Text = .Range("A" & i).Value
                TextBox2.Text = .Range("B" & i).Value
                '
                '~~> And So on load the rest
                '

                CurRecord = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

'~~> Next Button
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    If CurRecord = 0 Then CurRecord = 1

    With ws
        For i = (CurRecord + 1) To lRow
            If .Range("G" & i).Value = "Y" Then
                TextBox1.Text = .Range("A" & i).Value
                TextBox2.Text = .Range("B" & i).Value
                '
                '~~> And So on load the rest
                '

                CurRecord = i
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next i

        If (i - 1) = lRow Then
            MsgBox "End of record reached"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**Followup from comments**

Try this (Untested)

```
'~~> Previous Button
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    If CurRecord = 2 Then
        MsgBox "Begining of record reached"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf CurRecord = 0 Then
        CurRecord = 3
    End If

    With ws
        For i = (CurRecord - 1) To 2 Step -1
            If .Range("G" & i).Value = "Y" Then
                TextBox1.Text = .Range("A" & i).Value
                TextBox2.Text = .Range("B" & i).Value
                '
                '~~> And So on load the rest
                '

                CurRecord = i
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next i

        If i = 2 Then
            MsgBox "Begining of record reached"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Just got a chance to try it and it works great. Only thing for some reason I'm having a tough time getting the "Previous" button to work. I tried `For i = (CurRecord - 1) To lRow` And `For i = lRow To (CurRecord + 1)` And `lRow To (CurRecord - 1)` but it does not seem to work. Wonder where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Sadly still struggling with coding the "Previous" buttun would really appreciate your help!

Comment: I have now tried `i = 1 To (CurRecord - 1)` but that just keeps leaping back to the very first row. Also tried `For i - (CurRecord - 1) To (CurRecord - 1)` but using this it gets stuck displaying one record. Help Please!

Comment: Sorry missed your comments. can you update your question with the `previous` button code?

Comment: Thanks again, the above code for "Previous" works fine only when row 2 has "Y" is the Status column. Should row 2 contain "N" in the "Status" column, then `MsgBox "Begining of record reached"` does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I was thinking about how to fix the "Previous" button in case row 2 has "N" as Status as maybe if there is a way to make it find the first row with "Y" in the Status column and set that as CurRecord. Unfortunately not sure on how to do that? Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

If you auto filter on "Y", then the navigation will only visit the rows that are visible (have the "Y" in them).  Simply:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A1:$G$1").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="Y"
```